# Frequency count of particular field appended to line without deleting duplicates

Tags: sorting, frequency, uniq

Trying to work out how to get a frequency appended or prepended to each line in a file WITHOUT deleting duplicate occurrences (which uniq can do for me).

So, if input file is:

```
mango
mango
banana
apple
watermelon
banana
```

I need output:

```
mango 2
mango 2
banana 2
apple 1
watermelon 1
banana 2
```

All the solutions I have seen delete the duplicates. In other words, what I DON'T want is:

```
mango 2
banana 2
apple 1
watermelon 1
```

Comment: Is it important to keep the same line ordering in the output file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you cannot do it in one pass without keeping everything in memory. If this is what you want to do, then use python/perl/awk/whatever. The algorithm is quite simple.

Let's do it with standard Unix tools. This is a bit cumbersome and can be improved but should do the work:

```
$ sort input | uniq -c > input.count
$ nl input | sort -k 2  > input.line
$ join -1 2 -2 2 input.line input.count | sort -k 2 | awk '{print $1 " " $3}
```

The first step is to count the number occurrences of a given word.

As you said you cannot both repeat and keep line ordering. So we have to fix that. The second step prepends the line number that we will use later to fix the ordering issue.

In the last step, we join the two temporary files on the original word, the second column contains the original line number sort we sort on this key and strip it from the final output.

Comment: Thanks. Your engine works, just trying to modify now so that it works for field separators other than spaces/tabs (or alternatively, I'll build a workaround that converts all spaces in the original input file into some non-space character like "#" and then at the end, reconvert back to spaces)